# Eliminate white between page loads Phonegap iOS

Tags: html, ios, webview, load, cordova

**I'm trying to eliminate the white flash between loading local pages within my iOS Phonegap app.**
I've tried everything but I still can see white between page loads.

I've tried making my html background black, using data-transition=none and also making the webView backgroundcolor clear.

**I've put::**

```
 NSLog(@"BEGIN EDIT - set webView to transparent");
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.webView setOpaque: NO];
NSLog(@"END EDIT - set webView to transparent");
```

**In the CDVInAppBrowser.m , in the CDVViewController.m and in the AppDelegate.m but nothing seems to work!** Maybe I'm placing the code in the wrong position.

Please someone just help me get rid of the white between page loads!

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap loading can be quite slow.  You may need to use the splash screen API to show and hide splash?  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

On the page above, also pay attention to iOS Quirk section.  Alternatively, have you try single page application with jQuery Mobile or AngularJS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using a splashscreen and it's not the solution since the white flash is BETWEEN page loads.
Also, it's not possible to make a single page aplication due to the magnitude of my app.
There must be a way to eliminate the white between page loads! I wouldn't mind if it's black instead, it doesn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I made a mobile application with Phonegap.
I don't know how do avoid these flashes but when you've built a simple app with only a few screens you could **implement all your HTML documents into one file** like:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div class="page" id="page-1">
              Content of page one
         </div>
         <div class="page" id="page-2" style="display:none;">
              Content of page two
         </div>
         <div class="page" id="page-3" style="display:none;">
              Content of page three
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you could **switch between the contents of each container by making it visible/invisible** for the user.

The idea behind this solution is that all of your **app's content will get loaded once** (at the beginning) and **with jQuery you will switch between the content** without these white flashes when the webbrowser has to render the new page the user has been redirected to.

This is a good solution only when your app does not contain too much contents.

Answer (score 0):

like I said, making the app a single file was not possible in this case due to the complexity of it and I don't mind if the white flashes between page loads are black since they don't take long. Here's the solution I've found using Phonegap 2.8 for iOS:

In the CDVViewController.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.opaque = NO;
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //the rest of the code…
```

Hope it's useful to someone else.